# In Coffeescript, how to construct a list of object using list comprehension?

Tags: coffeescript

I tried to create a list of objects using comprehension in Coffeescript..

```
    photos =
          lat: r.latitude
          lng: r.longitude
          url: r.url
          caption: r.contentName
          thumbnail: r.url
          video: null
    for r in res
```

But it will not work.. Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code creates a single object in `photos` and then loops over `res` without the loop doing anything. You want to say:

```
photos = for r in res
    lat: r.latitude
    lng: r.longitude
    url: r.url
    caption: r.contentName
    thumbnail: r.url
    video: null
```

If you wanted to do it in the one-liner form, you'd have to say:

```
photos = (lat: r.latitude, ... for r in res)
```

with a big mess to create the object in place of the `...` of course. And yes, the parentheses are required if you wanted to do it that way due to the high precedence of assignment.